# Simple wrapper for member function pointers with known signature

Tags: c++, template, networking, pointers

I always wanted to know how to pass member functions as arguments, and then I stumbled across templates that could automatically deduce types, and so I rejoiced! This is used in a Publisher-Subscriber system for a game server. I wanted the subscribing to individual packet 'types' (i.e. by enum) to be simple at the calling site.

```
/**
* Wrapper struct for callbacks fired when RakNet::Packet*s arrive.
* TargetObj is used to identify this callback by which object it is bound to.
*/
struct PacketCallback
{
    template <typename Obj>
    PacketCallback(void(Obj::*mf)(const RakNet::Packet*), Obj* obj)
        : TargetObj(obj)
    {
        Func = std::bind(mf, obj, std::placeholders::_1);
    }

    std::function<void(const RakNet::Packet*)> Func;
    void* TargetObj = nullptr;
};
```

Used thus:

```
class ClientManagementTest : public INetworkSubscriber
{
public:

    virtual void Subscribe(NetworkPublisher* a_networkPublisher) override
    {
        a_networkPublisher->Register(ID_NEW_INCOMING_CONNECTION,
            PacketCallback(&ClientManagement::OnClientConnected, this));

        a_networkPublisher->Register(ID_CONNECTION_LOST,
            PacketCallback(&ClientManagement::OnClientDisconnected, this));

        a_networkPublisher->Register(ID_DISCONNECTION_NOTIFICATION,
            PacketCallback(&ClientManagement::OnClientDisconnected, this));
    }


    virtual void Unsubscribe(NetworkPublisher* a_networkPublisher) override
    {
        a_networkPublisher->UnregisterAll(this);
    }

    void OnClientConnected(const RakNet::Packet* a_packet)
    {
        printf("Someone connected\n");
    }

    void OnClientDisconnected(const RakNet::Packet* a_packet)
    {
        printf("Someone disconnected\n");
    }

};
```

Are there any glaring flaws or possible improvements, here? Perhaps something that's incredibly unsafe?

For context, the function pointer is invoked thus, where the publisher stores the callbacks in the form `std::map<int, std::vector<PacketCallback>> m_subscribers;`:

```
void NetworkPublisher::NotifySubscribers(int a_packetType, RakNet::Packet* a_packet)
{
    auto it = m_subscribers.find(a_packetType);
    if (it != m_subscribers.end())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < it->second.size(); ++i)
        {
            it->second[i].Func(a_packet);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm really happy with it, but would appreciate criticism.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the brief answer, typing on phone.

Your `NetworkPublisher` should have `Register(int signal, std::function<void()> callback)`

And then simply do:

```
publisher.Register(WHATEVER_SIGNAL, std::bind(&MyClass::MySignalCallback, this));
```

This way you dont need the `PacketCallback` class and your subscriber interface is more generally usable as you can now pass lamdas and free functions as well. Further more your `NotifySubscribers` will simplify a bit.

Side note: You might want to consider using smart pointers instead of raw pointers. Or references if null is not an allowed argument.

**Edit: In reply to comments, this is one way I would consider of doing it:**

```
enum class SignalType{
   NewConnection,
   ConnectionLost
};

const std::array<SignalType,2> AllSignalTypes = {
    SignalType::NewConnection,
    SignalType::ConnectionLost};

class ISubscriber{
public:
    virtual bool supportsSignal(SignalType signalType) const = 0;
    virtual void signal(SignalType signalType, const RakNet::Packet& packet) = 0;
}

class Publisher{
public:
    void registerSubscriber(const std::shared_ptr<ISubscriber>& subscriber){
        for(auto& type : AllSignalTypes){
            if(subscriber->supportsSignal(type)){
                // TODO: Check for duplicates or change to std::unordered_set<weak_ptr>
                subscribers[type].emplace_back(subscriber);
            }
        }
    }

    void signal(SignalType signalType, const RakNet::Packet& packet){
        forEachLiveSubscriber(signalType, [&packet](const std::shared_ptr<ISubscriber>& subscriber){
            subscriber->signal(signalType, packet);
            return true;
        });
    }

    void unregisterAll(const ISubscriber& subscriber){
        // Technically not necessary but for good measure
        for(auto& type : AllSignalTypes){
            forEachLiveSubscriber(signalType, [&packet](const std::shared_ptr<ISubscriber>& sharedSubscriber){
                return sharedSubscriber.get() != &subscriber;
            });
        }
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<SignalType, std::vector<std::weak_ptr<ISubscriber>>> subscribers;

    template<typename Callable>
    void forEachLiveSubscriber(SignalType signalType, Callable&& callback){
        auto& signalSubscribers = subscribers[signalType];

        auto it = signalSubscribers.begin();
        while(it != signalSubscribers.end()){
            auto& strongPtr = it->lock();
            if(strongPtr && callback(strongPtr)){
                it++;
            }
            else{
                // The subscriber has destructed without unregistering,
                // Or the callback requested us to remove it.
                it = signalSubscribers.erase(it);
            }
        }
    }
}

class MySubscriber : public ISubscriber{
    bool supportsSignal(SignalType signalType) const override{
        return signalType == NewConnection || signalType == ConnectionLost;
    }

    void signal(SignalType signalType, const RakNet::Packet& packet) override{
        switch(signalType){
            case NewConnection:
                std::cout<<"Someone connected"<<std::endl;
                break;
            case ConnectionLost:
                std::cout<<"Someone lost connection"<<std::endl;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that by using `shared_ptr` we get access to `weak_ptr` which in turn allows lazy garbage collection of the subscribers. In turn this means that a subscriber doesn't have to unregister if all shared pointers to it just simply die.

The above code is untested pseudocode. Some assembly may be required :)

Comment: Hi Emily, thanks for the advice! Part of the reason I used the struct was so I could store the obj alongside the function pointer, so I could do [this](http://i.imgur.com/ebUuRgk.png).  Is it doable some other way? std::function doesn't seem to support pulling the obj ptr back out.

Re. raw pointers - just following how games libraries and engines do it. RakNet gives me the Packet* pointer raw :)

Comment: @HateDread Re. raw pointers. Simply insert the raw pointer into a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` with a suitable `Deleter`. I will edit with an update for your example.

Answer (score 2):

### PacketCallback

Encapsulation - currently anyone can modify either member, and only the intended functionality should be exposed, e.g.

```
class PacketCallback
{
public:
    template <typename Obj>
    PacketCallback(void(Obj::*mf)(const RakNet::Packet*), Obj* obj)
        : TargetObj(obj)
    {
        Func = std::bind(mf, obj, std::placeholders::_1);
    }

    bool isTarget(void* other) 
    {
        return other == TargetObj;
    }

    void operator()(const RakNet::Packet* packet)
    {
        Func(packet);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(const RakNet::Packet*)> Func;
    void* TargetObj = nullptr;
};
```

### NetworkPublisher

Rather than using a map of vectors, you could instead use a [multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

```
std::multimap<int, PacketCallback> m_subscribers;

void NetworkPublisher::NotifySubscribers(int a_packetType, RakNet::Packet* a_packet)
{
    auto rng = m_subscribers.equal_range(a_packetType);
    for (auto it = rng.first; it != rng.second; ++it)
    {
        (*it)(a_packet);
    }

}
```

Comment: A `range-for` would make that last part much nicer:  `for (auto &sub : rng) { sub(a_packet); }`

Comment: Yes, although a pair of iterators isn't directly usable in a range-for, something like `for (auto &sub : boost::make_iterator_range(rng) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

One important thing not mentioned yet in the other reviews is that this is likely to be quite unsafe because there's no assurance that when a callback is invoked that the associated object still exists.  For example:

```
NetworkPublisher nwp;

int badSubscribe() {
    ClientManagementTest cmt;   // create on stack
    cmd.subscribe(&nwp);        // subscribe to global nwp
} // cmt is destroyed, but the callbacks still exist

// later, when a RakNet::Packet is received,
// member functions of the no longer existing cmt are invoked
// which is undefined behavior
```

The way to deal with this is to assure that the object will continue to exist when the callback is invoked, and one way to assure that is to use [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Specifically, one would derive `ClientManagementTest` from `std::enable_shared_from_this` and then return a `std::shared_ptr` to the object rather than simply `this` or a pointer to the member function.