# Callback class to callback member (virtual) functions

Tags: c++, c++11, template, callback

After looking at [a post on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148824/simple-wrapper-for-member-function-pointers-with-known-signature) I found that pointers to member functions are incredibly hard to use, especially as callbacks. The current solution doesn't solve the problem mentioned in the linked post, but tries to get rid of the type erasure (i.e. `std::function<>`) by making the target type explicit. I tried to solve lifetime/ownership issue with something else than `std::shared_ptr<>`, but found that it is impossible without relying on programmer to take care of that. So, I ended up with `std::shared_ptr<>` as a solution.

So, here is the code:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename Func>
class member_callback;

template <typename T, typename R, typename ... ArgTypes>
class member_callback<T, R(ArgTypes...)>
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> object;
    R(T::* callback)(ArgTypes ...);
public:
    using function_pointer = R(T::*)(ArgTypes ...);

    member_callback(const std::shared_ptr<T>& ptr, R(T::* function)(ArgTypes...)) :
        object(ptr),
        callback(function)
    {}

    member_callback(std::shared_ptr<T>&& ptr, R(T::* function)(ArgTypes...)) :
        object(std::move(ptr)),
        callback(function)
    {}

    R operator()(ArgTypes&& ... args)
    {
        return ((*object).*callback)(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> get()
    {
        return object;
    }

    function_pointer get_function()
    {
        return callback;
    }
};
```

It does one tradeoff though, you can't make a vector of them and call member functions of completely unrelated classes. Nevertheless, you'll still be able to invoke virtual functions, and they will work as expected according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087600/pointers-to-virtual-member-functions-how-does-it-work).

From the first glance it might look useless. **But it is not!** It becomes extremely useful when you're making a menu (1. ... 2. ... 3. ...) and want to invoke a function on the single object. So, here is the example:

```
#include "member_callback.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class integer
{
    int x;
public:
    integer():
            x(0)
    {}

    integer& operator++()
    {
        ++x;
        return *this;
    }

    integer& operator--()
    {
        --x;
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const integer& i);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const integer& i)
{
    os << "Currently number is: " << i.x << '\n';
}

void print_menu()
{
    static auto message = "Type the specified number to invoke the command.\n";
    static auto menu = "0. Increment\n1. Decrement\nAnything else to exit\n";

    std::cout << message << menu;
}

int main()
{
    auto object = std::make_shared<integer>();

    std::vector<member_callback<integer, integer&()>> actions{{object, &integer::operator++},
                                                              {object, &integer::operator--}};

    std::cout << "Welcome to dummy program!\n";
    std::cout << *object;

    unsigned int response =  -1;
    print_menu();
    std::cin >> response;
    while (response < 2)
    {
        actions[response]();
        std::cout << *object;
        print_menu();
        std::cin >> response;
    }

    std::cout << "Goodbye!\n";
}
```

If code will ever get changed you can find it [here](https://github.com/simmplecoder/custom-library/blob/master/member_callback.hpp).

I would like a review to focus on the easy of use. Also, does the code provide fine grained control? It will require dealing with `std::shared_ptr<>`, but I think it is mostly ok. Any other review points are welcome!

Comment: Ahh. I see it is a `shared_ptr` you will need to dereference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, the design looks reasonable.  However, I can't shake the feeling that [Lambda expressions](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) are a good (maybe even better) fit here.

For example, instead of

```
member_callback(object, &integer::--);
```

you could use a Lambda expression:

```
[&] () { return object--; }
```

This is almost as short, and has some additional advantages:

- You aren't effectively "reinventing the wheel".  Although I wouldn't say your `member_callback` class is precisely the same as a lambda, it's pretty close.
- I'm not qualified to say whether your code conforms to the C++ 11 specification.  But assuming it does, you are relying on relatively obscure portions of the specification.  This has some practical problems:

  - Others might have a hard time understanding and verifying your code.
  - Compilers often don't conform as strictly to the spec as we would like.  So you might find that your code is not portable, even if it does conform the the spec.
- You noted that one of the drawbacks of your approach is that you cannot mix functions to different types of objects.  With lambdas, you *can* combine functions that work on different types of objects.  You aren't just limited to objects of a single (base) type (in your case, `integer`).  Likewise, you can define functions that operate on more than one object, or even none at all (e.g., produce a constant value).  Or, you could combine functions.
- Lambdas open the door to higher-order approaches.  For example, if you [Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the `member_callback` function, you can partially instantiate a callback:

  - With the order you have `(object, function)`, you can construct a factory for working on a single object.  For example (eliding types for brevity):

    ```
    factory = member_callback_curried(object);

    // Sometime later, perhaps in a different scope
    dec = factory([] (integer& obj) { return obj--; });
    inc = factory([] (integer& obj) { return obj++; });
    ```
  - Reversing the order to `(function, object)`, you can construct a factory for working with the specified function:

    ```
    factory = callback_member_curried([&] (integer& obj) { return obj-- });

    // Sometime later, perhaps in a different scope
    dec_o1 = factory(obj1); // function that decrements obj1
    dec_o2 = factory(obj2); // function that decrements obj2
    ```

Comment: @Incomputable, why do you think lambdas are incompatible with `std::shared_ptr<>`?

Comment: @Incomputable, yes, it probably makes the most sense to take them by value.  I don't know why you shouldn't be able to store `shared_ptr`s in a `vector` of type `std::vector<shared_ptr<std::function<...>>`.

Comment: @Incomputable, first of all, this is the first time *you* have mentioned `std::function<>`.  Second, if that *is* the "whole point", then stackoverflow would be a better fit for that question.  You asked for a review of your code, and that is what I gave.